# Getting my local ip address by android studio code

Tags: android, android-studio

How to get my local internal ip address by the code of Android studio
I tried all the codes in similar questions but all faild
If some help i,ll be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

This below code gives you the local ip address.

```
private String getIpAccess() {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
        final String formatedIpAddress = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
        return formatedIpAddress; //192.168.31.2
}
```

Try this code for hotspot. It might work.

```
private String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                    .nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                    .getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
                            + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
    }
    return ip;
}
```

Comment: This works when your network is WiFi (not hotspot). Also, Try the updated answer!

Comment: Actually my network is WIFI not hotspot but i tried the 2nd code also it is not correct , it is giving FEC1-5054-FF-FE10 and 10.0.4.13                                     i need somthing like 192.168.1.7